# Construction of Morse function on $RP^1$

Tags: morse-theory

I wanna construct Morse function on $RP^1$ with one critical point,how can i do it.
P.S. i wanna construct such function on every $RP^n$,but at first wanna understand it on the simplest example.

Comment: Any smooth function on a closed manifold has at least *two* critical points, a maximum and a minimum (if they’re the same, the function is constant and it has nothing but critical points…). For your problem: $\mathbb{RP}^1$ is exactly $S^1$, so finding a function with two critical points shouldn’t be too hard… what can you try?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood how to build morse functions on $RP^1$ and $CP^1$ using height functions on $S^1$ and $S^2$